# Printf with unfixed length

Tags: c, printf

I need to

> printf(%?d)

Where '?' is some int. How can I do it?
I'm using pure c.
I've tried to work with const char* array. But there was no result.

Answer (score 1):

See the [printf man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf):

```
int width = 16;
int value = 42;
printf("%*d\n", width, value);
```

Output:

```
              42
```

<kbd>[LIVE DEMO](http://ideone.comc2I6oh)</kbd>